# Python 3.7 + PIL How can I change pixel shading to equivalent alpha transparency level 0-255

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Unable figure out how to convert pixel color list to equivalent alpha transparency in white.

```
pixel_data = list(img.getdata())
print(pixel_data)
alpha_range = range(0, 256)  # increase count
color_range = range(256, -1, -1)  # decrease count
for i, pixel in enumerate(pixel_data):
    if pixel[:3] == (255, 255, 255):
        pixel_data[i] = (255, 255, 255, 0)
img.putdata(pixel_data)
print(list(pixel_data))
```

I expect to parse a grey scale image's pixels then convert to equivalent alpha transparency level:

```
.R., .G., .B. = .R., .G., .B., Alpha 
255, 255, 255 = 255, 255, 255, 0
254, 254, 254 = 255, 255, 255, 1
253, 253, 253 = 255, 255, 255, 2
252, 252, 252 = 255, 255, 255, 3
..., ..., ... = ..., ..., ..., 4
..., ..., ... = ..., ..., ..., 5
..., ..., ... = ..., ..., ..., 6
..., ..., ... = ..., ..., ..., .
..., ..., ... = ..., ..., ..., 255
```

I'd like the end result to be all white and shaded with matching levels of opacity(alpha transparency)

Provided image to show what the white end result should be like.  Blue background for easy viewing:
[image: Provided image to show what the white end result should be like. Blue background for easy viewing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to add a few more bits to Mark's code and achieve the exact results I wanted.  Thank you!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from PIL import Image

# Open image
img = Image.open('firefox.png').convert('RGBA')
img2 = img.copy()

# Extract Red channel
r, g, b, a = img.split()

# Generate Alpha channel as (255-Red)
alpha_r = r.point(lambda p: 255 - p)
alpha_g = g.point(lambda p: 255 - p)
alpha_b = b.point(lambda p: 255 - p)
alpha_a = b.point(lambda p: 255 - p)

# Fill original image with white
img.paste((255, 255, 255), box=(0, 0, img.width, img.height))

# Add in alpha channel
img.putalpha(alpha_r), img.putalpha(alpha_g), img.putalpha(alpha_b), img.putalpha(alpha_a)

# crop out white area
img = Image.composite(img, img2, img2)

# Save
img.save('result.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean this:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open image and ensure it has an alpha channel
im = Image.open('image.png').convert('RGBA')

# Make into Numpy array, shape [h,w,4]
ni = np.array(im)

# Set the alpha channel of each pixel to "255 - red"
ni[...,3] = 255 - ni[...,0]

# Set the RGB of each pixel to white (255,255,255)
ni[:,:,(0,1,2)] = 255

# Make back into PIL Image and save
Image.fromarray(ni).save('result.png')
```

---

If, for some reason, you object to **Numpy**, you can do it in straight PIL/Pillow like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# Open image, ensuring in RGB mode, rather than palette or greyscale
im = Image.open('image.png').convert('RGB')

# Extract Red channel
R, _, _ = im.split()

# Generate Alpha channel as (255-Red)
Alpha = R.point(lambda p: 255-p)

# Fill original image with white
im.paste((255,255,255),box=(0,0,im.width,im.height))

# Add in alpha channel
im.putalpha(Alpha)

# Save
im.save('result.png')
```

Comment: This is near perfect wow! so simply made also.  This code overwrites existing alpha channels which i do not want to happen.  I'm using the for loop above to rid blacks/white that numpy took over.

Comment: Is there a way to have im.putalpha(Alpha) not affect the existing alpha transparent areas?  Currently it takes over existing transparent areas to black or white.  

and my previous script can't detect the new white or black as a color to remove.